# Jquery eq selector not working on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, offset

First, I already did a lot of investigation here on stackoverflow without luck. It should be simple... I dynamically add the class `.ocurrencia_busqueda` to a lot of spans. If I do `$('.ocurrencia_busqueda').length` it returns 64 occurrences. But when trying to get the offset of each ocurrence, I always get the same values, both trying the code from console or hardcoded in the script:

**JS**

```
$('.ocurrencia_busqueda:eq(0)').offset()
Object { top=-434.79998779296875,  left=566.75}
$('.ocurrencia_busqueda:eq(1)').offset()
Object { top=-434.79998779296875,  left=566.75}
$('.ocurrencia_busqueda:eq(2)').offset()
Object { top=-434.79998779296875,  left=566.75}
```

I already tried to get the offset with

```
$('.ocurrencia_busqueda').eq(N)
```

instead of

```
$('.ocurrencia_busqueda:eq(N)')
```

without luck.

The function that should return the offset is:

```
var offset = 0;
function busca_texto() {    
    var divPosition = $('.ocurrencia_busqueda').eq(parseInt(mioffset)).offset();                        
    console.log(divPosition);
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: divPosition.top}, "slow");    
    mioffset++;
}
```

The spans are like 
**HTML**

```
<span style="color:red" class="ocurrencia_busqueda" onclick="javascript:console.log($(this).offset());">TEXT</span>
```

and when clicking on the element, the onclick event gives me a different offset for each element. Each time the `busca_texto()` function is invoked, the variable `mioffset` increases, and should return the offset of the next occurrence, but it always return the same, either when the variable is increasing without problem.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: If you are trying to get the offset of every element, why not just use $().each() ?

Comment: `eq(x)` isn't broken. [Example using your class](http://jsfiddle.net/begf2m04/1/). For us to help you, you'll have to produce an [MCVE](/help/mcve), ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` buttton) right here on the site.

Comment: I need to access them from a function that uses a variable as the number to be inserted on the `eq()`. I edited my post to add the function

Comment: @CornezuelodelCenteno: It doesn't matter (and I don't see any functions in the question -- ah, there's one there now, *after* I refreshed before commenting), it works regardless. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/begf2m04/2/ **Again**: If you can provide an MCVE, we can help you. Continuing without an MCVE is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: The posted code will fail with a TypeError, since `mioffset` is not defined prior to first use and you're trying to read its value. (You have an `offset` declared, but no `mioffset`.)

Comment: I was adding it, now it's updated ;) I'm going to try with each(), but I still don't understand why it isn't working with `:eq()` or `.eq()`, I don't get why I need to use `each()` instead

Comment: @CornezuelodelCenteno: *"I don't get why I need to use each() instead"* **You don't**, as my fiddles demonstrate.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: When iterating with `.each()` at the end of the fuction, it returns all the different offsets without problem, but when inserting on the console `$('.ocurrencia_busqueda:eq(N)').offset()` and changing N with 0, 1, 2, 3..... I always receive the same offset. I still don't understand why

Comment: did you mean `:eq(0)` in that string? because `N` would be interpreted as the string `N`, not a number.

Comment: Yes, with `N` I wanted to say "any number". Even if I use `:eq(0)` or `:eq(1)` or `:eq(2)`... the offset returned is always the same

Comment: if it works with .each using the same selector, i don't believe you unfortunately, because that isn't possible unless they all actually do have the same offset.

Answer (score 1):

Normally it's work check live example bellow :

```js
console.log( $('.ocurrencia_busqueda:eq(0)').offset() );
console.log( $('.ocurrencia_busqueda:eq(1)').offset() );
console.log( $('.ocurrencia_busqueda:eq(2)').offset() );

//Object {top: 8, left: 8}
//Object {top: 8, left: 60.875}
//Object {top: 8, left: 113.75}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="color:red" class="ocurrencia_busqueda" onclick="javascript:console.log($(this).offset());">TEXT1</span>

<span style="color:red" class="ocurrencia_busqueda" onclick="javascript:console.log($(this).offset());">TEXT2</span>

<span style="color:red" class="ocurrencia_busqueda" onclick="javascript:console.log($(this).offset());">TEXT3</span>
```

Try it using using `each()` function :

```js
$('.ocurrencia_busqueda').each(function(index){
    console.log( $('.ocurrencia_busqueda:eq('+index+')').offset() );
})

//Object {top: 8, left: 8}
//Object {top: 8, left: 60.875}
//Object {top: 8, left: 113.75}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="color:red" class="ocurrencia_busqueda" onclick="javascript:console.log($(this).offset());">TEXT1</span>

<span style="color:red" class="ocurrencia_busqueda" onclick="javascript:console.log($(this).offset());">TEXT2</span>

<span style="color:red" class="ocurrencia_busqueda" onclick="javascript:console.log($(this).offset());">TEXT3</span>
```

Comment: I'd say the most likely reason is that the OP's code works. So the question cannot be usefully answered at present, just guessed at. Rather than posting guesses, we should wait until the question can be usefully answered.

Comment: Thanks, with `each()` it seems to work, but  because of performance I need to access one specific occurrence of the class each time, not iterate through everyone, that's why I want to do it with `eq`

Comment: You're welcome bro, it's work in the fiddle and live example here i'm not sure why not in your case, try to put your code inside ready function that may help.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like an issue with the class `.ocurrencia_busqueda` you are adding to the span elements. Check if the class has `position:absolute` declared as an attribute. That is the only scenario what i can think of when the offsets would be same for all `span` elements.

Here's an example which shows the problem you might be facing :

http://jsfiddle.net/ywhjLn7j/